# How to select record where begin date and end date between two dates of mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to ask about mysql query, if I have a table like the image below, how do I make the query look for start date & end date.

illustrated below if the unit code from the start date 2020-02-01 to the end date 2020-02-04 has been blocked. so if we select the start date 2020-02-01 & end date 2020-02-04 or start date 2020-02-02 & end date 2020-02-04 we still take the data. if more or less from the start & end date we will not take the data.

I use a query like this can not:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_ref ​​WHERE orders_date>> '2020-02-01' AND exit_date <= '2020-02-04'
```

Please help

[image: ph]

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below query:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_ref where orders_date BETWEEN CAST('2020-02-01' AS DATE)
  and CAST('2020-02-04' AS DATE);
```

OR

```
  SELECT * FROM tb_ref where orders_date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-04';
```

Comment: he has two different column.

Comment: I have tried by query SELECT * FROM tb_ref WHERE tanggal_masuk >= '2020-02-01' AND tanggal_keluar <= '2020-02-02'. but what if the case he entered the entry date 2020-01-01 and exit date 2020-02-02 which dated 2020-02-01 until 2020-02-02 was already filled?

Comment: change the column name and value of date in sql query.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Use `>=` instead of `>>`:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_ref ​​WHERE orders_date >= '2020-02-01' AND exit_date <= '2020-02-04'
```

Comment: sorry I was mistaken when posting it

Comment: I have tried by query SELECT * FROM tb_ref WHERE tanggal_masuk >= '2020-02-01' AND tanggal_keluar <= '2020-02-02'. but what if the case he entered the entry date 2020-01-01 and exit date 2020-02-02 which dated 2020-02-01 until 2020-02-02 was already filled?